# Java Working with Threads

Tags: java, multithreading

I have two types of threads

Thread1's : Populate a multi-thread safe data structure

Thread2's : Search for a specific key in the data structure

I want to start thread2's before there is any data in the map, so the way I am doing so is :

```
//Main
spawn 3 new thread 2's(name, map)
spawn 3 new thread 1's(name, value, map)

let threads handle rest

//Thread1
private string name;
private string value; 

public void run(){
    try{
        synchronized(map){
           map.put(key, value);
           map.notifyAll();
        }
    }
}

//Thread2

private string name;
public void run(){
    try{
        synchronized(map){
           while (map.size() <1){
               map.wait();
           }
        }

        if (map.containsKey(name){
             System.out.println(name, map.get(name));
        }
    }
}
```

The behavior I want: As Thread1's put pairs into the map, thread2's check if their name matches a pair and if so print it's value.

The behavior I am getting:

```
//Result
Putting bluecheese  -- white//This line is printed in thread 1 right before the map.put call
Putting chipotle -- food
Putting dogbone -- dog

food 

**** should have been food, dog, white (no order to this, just make sure we account for them all)


//Result #2
Putting bluecheese  -- white//This line is printed in thread 1 right before the map.put call
Putting chipotle -- food
Putting dogbone -- dog

white, dog //This line is printed in thread 2. 

**** should have been white, dog, food (no order, again just make sure we account for them all)
```

Comment: It's hard to tell exactly what you are doing. Please post a short but complete example which we can use to reproduce what your are describing.

Comment: If you have two threads outputting to the console, their output will, of course, be intermixed. If that isn't what you want, don't do that.

Comment: I've added some psuedoish code to try and show what I am trying to accomplish.

Comment: the issue is not the order in which the output is printed. The issue is sometimes the output doesn't find the matches in the map, even though they are there.

Answer (score 0):

Calls to wait/notify must be inside a synchronize block and in a while-loop:

Try:

```
synchronize(map) {
    while(!map.size() > 0){
         try {
             map.wait()
         catch(InterruptedException e) {}
    }
}
```

Then notify the thread after you have put some items in with: `map.notify()`.